# Elasticsearch bool filter for multiple conditions on same element of array

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to create a query/filter that matches a document only if a number of conditions are met **on the same item** of an array.

Let's say this is the document:

```
{
  arr: [
    { "f1" : "a" , f2 : true },
    { "f1" : "b" , f2 : false}
  ]
}
```

I want to be able to retrieve documents that have N conditions matching on the same element. For example: `arr.f1 == "a" AND arr.f2 == true` should match the document but `arr.f1 == "b" AND arr.f2 == true` should not.

I'm trying nested bool filters (I have other filters apart from this one) but it doesn't work, something in the lines of

```
"bool" : {
    "must": [
        { some other filter },
        {"bool": {"must" : [
            {"term" : {"arr.f1" : "a"}},
            {"term" : {"arr.f2" : true}},
        ] }}
    ]
}
```

Any idea how to do that?
thanks

**edit**: 
I changed the mapping and now a nested query works as per Val's response. I'm now not able to do an "exists" filter on the nested field:

A simple `{ "filter" : {"exists" : { "field" : "arr" } } }` search returns no hits. How do I do that?

edit: It looks like I need to do a nested exists filter to check that a field inside the nested object exists.
something like:

```
"filter" : {
       "nested" : {"path" : "arr", "filter" : {"exists" : { "field" : "f1" } }}
}
```

edit:
argh - now highlight doesn't work anymore:

```
   "highlight" : {
        "fields" : [
            {"arr.f1" : {}},
        ]
    }
```

Worked around that by adding `include_in_parent : true` and querying both the nested field and the root object. It's just awful. If anyone has a better idea, they're more than welcome!

```
{   
    "query" : {
        "bool" : {
            "must": [
                {"term" : { "arr.f1" : "a" }},
                { "nested" : { "path" : "arr", 
                   "query" :  { "bool" : { "must" : [ 
                        {"term" : { "arr.f1" : "a" }},
                        {"term" : { "arr.f2" : true }}
                   ] } } 
                }}
            ]
        }
    },
    "highlight" : {
        "fields" : [
            {"arr.f1" : {}},
        ]
    }
}
```

In case you're wondering: it's legacy stuff. I can't reindex right now (that would be the obvious solution) and I need a quick & dirty workaround

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the type of your `arr` field as [`nested`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-nested-type.html) like this:

```
{
    "your_type": {
        "properties": {
            "arr": {
                "type": "nested",
                "properties": {
                    "f1": {"type":"string"},
                    "f2": {"type":"boolean"}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you need to use a [`nested` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html):

```
{
    "nested" : {
        "path" : "arr",
        "query" : {
            "bool" : {
                "must" : [
                    {
                        "term" : {"arr.f1" : "a"}
                    },
                    {
                        "term" : {"arr.f2" : true}
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Your `exists` filter needs to specify the full field path

```
"filter" : {
       "nested" : {"path" : "arr", "filter" : {"exists" : { "field" : "arr.f1" } }}
}
```

Comment: nice. How do I do an "exists" filter on a nested array? It doesn't seem to work anymore. Just filtering "exists" : { "field" : "arr" } now returns no docs.

Comment: done. Just a simple exists filter on "arr" returns nothing even though all the docs have it.

Comment: Ok the "final" version of the query is as bad as it can get. I need both highlighting (because I need to know which of the nested objects matched) and nested filtering. 

before anyone asks: it's legacy stuff. I can't reindex right now and I need a quick & dirty workaround.

Comment: Well, if you cannot reindex, does it mean you could not change the mapping in the first place? that's probably why the `exists` filter and the highlighting doesn't work anymore.

Comment: you're right. I was actually looking for the best solution to be able to choose what to do with the legacy db. 
I found out highlighting doesn't work with nested queries, it's a known "bug" (or missing feature, I don't know).