# Elastic Search nested object query

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I have a elastic search index collection like below,

```
"_index":"test",
"_type":"abc",
"_source":{
       "file_name":"xyz.ex"
       "metadata":{
          "format":".ex"
          "profile":[
                     {"date_value" : "2018-05-30T00:00:00",
                     "key_id" : "1",
                     "type" : "date",
                     "value" : [ "30-05-2018" ]
                      },
                      {
                       "key_id" : "2",
                       "type" : "freetext",
                       "value" : [ "New york" ]
                       }
}
```

Now I need to search for document by matching `key_id` to its value. (`key_id` is some field whose value is stored in `"value"`)
Ex. For `key_id='1'`field, if it's `value = "30-05-2018"` it should match the above document.

I tried mapping this as a nested object, But I am not able to write query to search with 2 or more `key_id` matching its respective value.

Comment: This answer may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32267353/elasticsearch-bool-filter-for-multiple-conditions-on-same-element-of-array/32267541#32267541

Comment: Thanks @Val, In the above link example arr: [
    { "f1" : "a" , f2 : true },
    { "f1" : "b" , f2 : false}
  ], How to query for both condition f1=a,f2=true and f1=b,f2=false?

Comment: i had same problem, it solved my problem also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I would do it. You need to AND together via `bool/filter` (or `bool/must`) two nested queries for each of the condition pair, since you want to match two different nested elements from the same parent document.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "metadata.profile",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "filter": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "metadata.profile.f1": "a"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "metadata.profile.f2": true
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "metadata.profile",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "filter": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "metadata.profile.f1": "b"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "metadata.profile.f2": false
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: For above document structure, is there any other way to query instead of  making it as nested object? Because I have some other data in the same document, which are not a nested object. But while I am doing simple search, it skips the nested documents.

Comment: Would you mind creating another question with your new issue?