# Filter the records from nested query - Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch

I am having nested array fields, I need to query and filter the records for that.
Sample

```
"test":{
  "name":[
     {
       "name": "vanaraj",
       "Age" : 26
     },
     {
       "name": "vanaraj",
       "Age" : 10
     },
     {
       "name": "ranjit",
       "Age" : 26
     },

    ]

}
```

Here how I need the query for below conditions,
  1. Where Name is equal to both ["vanaraj","ranjit"] to fetch
  2. Add condition where Age > 25 for only "vanaraj"

I need a query like below, but it is not working.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "data.test.name",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "filter": [
                  {
                    "terms": {
                      "data.test.name.name": ["vanaraj","ranjit"]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "data.test.name",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "filter": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "data.test.name.name": "vanaraj"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "range": {
                       "data.test.name.Age": {
                                            "gt": 25
                        }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Mapping :

```
{  
   "mappings":{  
      "properties":{  
         "test":{  
            "properties":{  
               "name":{  
                  "type":"nested",               
                  "properties":{  
                     "Age":{  
                        "type":"long"
                     },
                     "name":{  
                        "type":"text",
                        "fields":{  
                           "keyword":{  
                              "type":"keyword",
                              "ignore_above":256
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: this answer should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50798830/4604579

Comment: I need a query like below , but it is not working.

Comment: Could you share your mapping info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your further clarification, the below code should help you:

### Solution:

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "test.name",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "test.name.name": "vanaraj"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "range": {
                      "test.name.Age": {
                        "gte": 26
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "test.name",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "test.name.name": "ranjith"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }  
}
```

The above solution would return you all the documents having `name` as `ranjith` OR if `name` is `vanaraj` and `age > 25`

Summary of query:

```
Bool 
 - Should
    - Must clause for name=vanaraj and age >= 26
    - Must clause for name=ranjith
```

### Updated Solution:

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "test.name",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "test.name.name": "vanaraj"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "range": {
                      "test.name.Age": {
                        "gte": 26
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "test.name",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "terms": {
                      "test.name.name": [
                        "abc",
                        "ranjit"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [
      {
          "nested": {
            "path": "test.name",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "terms": {
                      "test.name.name": [
                        "vanaraj"
                      ]
                    }
                  },{
                    "range": {
                      "test.name.Age": {
                        "lte": 25
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Please run the above and let me know if this helps!

Comment: In Your Query it is filtering the range for all fields, i need only for Vanaraj, Age > 26, In your case for "abc" it should return two results "abc" , Age =26 and Age 10.

Comment: So if i understand correctly, it should be *retrieve all documents where you have "ranjit" **AND** (vanaraj only if Age >= 26)*, the above query does that exactly **only if** your mapping is what I've mentioned. Otherwise it won't work.

Comment: Its like Case when Vanaraj and Age > 26 remaining all records should fetch.

Comment: In my mapping "name" is only nested not "test".

Comment: @user2602635 Please check the answer now and let me know if it helps!

Comment: I have one concern here instead of {
                    "match": {
                      "test.name.name": "ranjith"
                    }
                  } i need like "terms": {
                      "test.name.name":["vanaraj", "ranjith","abc"]
                    }
                  } whether this is possible

Comment: Term Queries are generally meant for `keyword` fields. You don't need to add `vanaraj` there though as its already used in separate clause.

Comment: But for me in the request payload for search it will come like this "name":["vanaraj","ranjith","abc"]. Age condition only I need to hardcode in the query. But there I need to use terms query only like above. In terms "vanaraj" should present and in "should"  "vanaraj" and "age" should present. Can you suggest a solution for this.

Comment: @user2602635 check the section `Updated Solution`. That should get you what you want. If you think your query is resolved, feel free to upvote/accept this answer.

Comment: Yeah Kamal , this will work but i need a solution like , inside terms "vanaraj" also should present like below {
          "terms": {
            "test.name.name": ["vanaraj",
              "abc",
              "ranjit"
            ]
          }
        }

Comment: That is not possible as for `vanaraj`, you have a clause of `age` as well. Hence you would need to separate out the two clauses. one for `vanaraj having age >= 26` and other to return for `abc, ranjit, def, ghi...etc`. Both these clauses should be combined in a `should` clause. You may want to take a step back and go through elasticsearch bool queries in first place before you jump on implementing a solution.

Comment: You can change `match` with `term` for `vanaraj` in the above query if that's what you are asking.

Comment: Yes but below terms also "vanaraj" should present

Comment: Doesn't make sense, then why have `vanaraj` with `age` clause. You are pulling all documents having `vanaraj` if you do that irrespective of `age`. Basically the only way to get what you want is by using the solution I've mentioned. You have to take a step back and understand what you get when you run the query in the way you want to run.

Comment: @user2602635 Ahh I've got to know the scenario where it won't work!! Hold one for a sec!!

Comment: @user2602635 Please try the `Updated Solution` now and let met know if that solves what you are looking for. I'm hoping this works now :|

Comment: Yes Kamal, It's working Now. Thanks a lot and your support.

Comment: I'm so happy you've got the solution. Feel free to upvote as well ;)

Comment: Kamal do you have any idea on this , it's related to this problem
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56477552/elastic-search-querybuilder-rangequery-for-greater-than-it-is-returning-from