# Elastic Search - QueryBuilder.rangeQuery for greater than it is returning "From" in the Query

Tags: elasticsearch

I have written a range query with gt (greaterthan) for a field.

The below Query I have written, but the query was generated is "From" not "gt".

Query in Java:
QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("data.amount").gt(10);

The response I should get :

```
{
       "range":{

            "data.amount":{
                      "gt": 10
               }
        }
}
```

But I am getting the below response :

```
{
       "range":{

            "data.amount":{
                        "from" : 10,
                        "to" : null,
                        "include_lower" : false,
                        "include_upper" : true,
                        "boost" : 1.0
               }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the same thing, it' just the API changed over time. Both versions are supported

Explanation:

`gt 10` actually means:

```
"from" : 10,
"to" : null,
"include_lower" : false,
"include_upper" : true
```

`gte 10` actually means:

```
"from" : 10,
"to" : null,
"include_lower" : true,
"include_upper" : true
```

`lt 10` actually means:

```
"from" : null,
"to" : 10,
"include_lower" : true,
"include_upper" : false
```

`lte 10` actually means:

```
"from" : null,
"to" : 10,
"include_lower" : true,
"include_upper" : true
```

Hope that explains your question